# TFS 2010 - Building out Nuget using TFS results in TFS error: Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild, nuget

I downloaded a standard copy of the Nuget web app and plan to use it in our corporate environment.  We use TFS 2010 to facilitate the builds from our local machine.  When I queue a new build on TFS for Nuget, the build fails with the error:

> Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the
>   Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and check
>   'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can also
>   give consent by setting the environment variable
>   'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.

**QUESTION:** do I need to do what it says above on the TFS build server, or on my local machine in Visual Studio?  How can I resolve this issue?  If this is in fact an issue on the TFS build server, and the build server doesn't allow to download missing packages, do I need to just download those packages and check them into Source Control?

Here's the log file that resulted from the build, which also contains the errors:

> Build started 9/19/2013 12:19:08 PM.
>        1>Project "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\NuGetGallery.sln" on node 1
>   (default targets).
>        1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
>            Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
>        1>Project "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\NuGetGallery.sln" (1) is
>   building
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\Website.csproj" (2) on
>   node 1 (default targets).
>        2>RestorePackages:
>            "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\packages.config" -o
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\packages"
>        1>Project "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\NuGetGallery.sln" (1) is
>   building "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\Facts.csproj"
>   (3) on node 2 (default targets).
>        3>RestorePackages:
>            "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\nuget.exe" install "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\packages.config"
>   -o "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\packages"
>        2>F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
>   error : Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open
>   the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and
>   check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can
>   also give consent by setting the environment variable
>   'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\Website.csproj]
>        2>F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
>   error MSB3073: The command
>   ""F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\packages.config" -o
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\packages"" exited with code 1.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\Website.csproj]
>        2>Done Building Project "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\Website.csproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.
>        3>F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
>   error : Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open
>   the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and
>   check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can
>   also give consent by setting the environment variable
>   'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\Facts.csproj]
>        3>F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
>   error MSB3073: The command
>   ""F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\packages.config" -o
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\packages"" exited with code 1.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\Facts.csproj]
>        3>Done Building Project "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\Facts.csproj" (default
>   targets) -- FAILED.
>        1>Done Building Project "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\NuGetGallery.sln" (default
>   targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> ```
>    "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\NuGetGallery.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>    "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\Website.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
>    (RestorePackages target) -> 
>      F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
> ```
>
> error : Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open
>   the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and
>   check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can
>   also give consent by setting the environment variable
>   'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\Website.csproj]
>            F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
>   error MSB3073: The command
>   ""F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\packages.config" -o
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\packages"" exited with code 1.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Website\Website.csproj]
>
> ```
>    "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\NuGetGallery.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>    "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\Facts.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
>      F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
> ```
>
> error : Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open
>   the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and
>   check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can
>   also give consent by setting the environment variable
>   'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\Facts.csproj]
>            F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9):
>   error MSB3073: The command
>   ""F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\packages.config" -o
>   "F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\packages"" exited with code 1.
>   [F:\Builds\2\Nuget\NuGetGallery\Sources\Facts\Facts.csproj]
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 4 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.82

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları, in the answer given to the duplicate question, "As a workaround, you can give consent by setting the EnableNuGetPackageRestore environment variable to true." - where do I set this at, at the build server level or my local machine?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I cannot modify my build server at all, so there's no way to set that environment variable on the build server.

Comment: Does [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetEnablePackageRestore/) help?